# What is the best code practice in this case?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am browsing directory where i saved logs , i am using tmpdir pytest fixture : so which one of the two examples is better written :
example 1 :

```
for root, dirname, files in os.walk(str(tmpdir + '/log/')):
    ....
```

example 2 :

```
directory = str(os.path.join(tmpdir, 'log'))
for root, dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
    ....
```

Which syntax i should use and why ?

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: "os.path.join" is better than string concatenation.

Comment: @MichaelButscher and `pathlib.Path` is cleaner, IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, if you will need to access that directory variable again then its best to have it as a variable.

If not, having the variable it might be considered more "readable" but it is slightly redundant to have it without a second use.